# Tool to create Repository for sharing android project on LAN

Tags: android, eclipse, repository, sharing, code-sharing

I am new to working on projects in a team. I need to Share an android project with my team placed at one local server machine with the other machines connected through LAN. We are using **Eclipse** for project development.

How can i place project code on one machine and then multiple people can work on it from their respected machines on same LAN. The programmers can **CheckIn/ CheckOut** the files and all.

Its just a start for me in this field so don't have much idea about this.

Comment: I use EGit https://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several options. Assuming you HAVE to work on a LAN network, there is [TFS for eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tfs-plug-eclipse#.U1VhknWSy0w).

However, if you do have a reliable internet connection, there are much more popular options such as [Git](https://github.com/) which allows you to have a 'master' branch with different team members working on local copies and then 'committing' changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed **tfs** plugin but can you please provide me a link or source that can help me set up the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** on my server machine. I am trying to add my server location like "http://10.228.18.171:8080/tfs/" in eclipse TFS **add server** section but its not working

Comment: @isumit, I would love to help and should have more free time later today. For starters, you say it is not working. Are there any error messages?

Comment: thanks. I am getting this error : the SOAP endpoint http://10.228.18.171:8080/tfs/Services/V1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted. HTTP status: 404

Comment: Do i need to install/ Configure TFS on my server machine ?

Comment: Of course, take a look at [Set Up TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561426.aspx) and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to go is to use a version control system (VCS).

There are mainly two types of version control systems.

1. Centralized (Eg. SVN)
2. Distributed (Eg. Git)

I would recommend you to go with Distributed VCS as it is more powerful and gives you more flexibility.

Try http://github.com or http://bitbucket.org

You can even setup your own git server

checkout http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: I am Looking for free options.I heard a lot about github but is it free for private repositories ?

Comment: github private repo is not free. you can use bitbucket free of cost for private repos for max of 5 users..